# How to query nearest date in ArcGIS Server REST?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql, arcgis-rest-api

How to query nearest date (today) in ArcGIS Server REST?

Table:

```
ID    NAME            DATA
1     test           2013-06-01 13:00:00
2     test1          2013-06-01 16:00:00
3     test2          2013-07-01 18:00:00
```

Expected result : query  ID = 3

Comment: Are you interacting directly with the REST api, or using another API such as the [ArcGIS Server Javascript API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi)?

Comment: Directly with the REST api

Comment: What is the underlying database (Oracle/MSSQL/FileGDB/... etc.)?

Comment: I use Oracl/Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer might not be the final solution, but I can provide some ideas about this question.

First, switch the Date to time format, according to:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Query_Map_Service_Dynamic_Layer/02r3000000z6000000/ (**Parameter 'time'**)

Then compare all the time data and pick the biggest number by using the max statisticType:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Query_Map_Service_Dynamic_Layer/02r3000000z6000000/ (**Parameter 'outStatistics'**)

outStatistics is supported on only those [layers/tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/02r3/02r3000000zr000000.htm) that indicate suppportsStatistics is true.